# how to re-use noise texture from geo nodes in (volume)shader

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to use the same noise data from geo nodes in a shader for its volume output. I fooled around with named (color) attributes but this will obviously be geometry based and not volumetric data anymore - is this possible at all? I'd like to avoid recreating the geo nodes  noise in the shader to keep it fully procedural